# AEM 6.3 Service Pack 1 com.adobe.cq.export.json cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation

Tags: osgi, aem

I am running a recently upgraded AEM 6.3 instance. Upgraded from 6.1

After installing AEM-6.3-Service-Pack-1, the com.adobe.cq.export.json bundle cannot resolve the com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation bundle

`com.adobe.cq.export.json` is version 0.0.12
`com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation` is version 2.8.4

The "Imported Packages" statement for com.adobe.cq.export.json has `"com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation,version=[2.8,3)` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations"`

Give that com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation is version 2.8.4 the import statement seems valid. What am I not seeing?

Error message below:

> *ERROR* [qtp998235579-61] org.apache.felix.http.jetty %bundles.pluginTitle: Cannot start
>   (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve
>   com.adobe.cq.export.json [660](R 660.0): missing requirement
>   [com.adobe.cq.export.json [660](R 660.0)] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0
>   ))) Unresolved requirements: [[com.adobe.cq.export.json [660](R
>   660.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0
>   )))]) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve
>   com.adobe.cq.export.json [660](R 660.0): missing requirement
>   [com.adobe.cq.export.json [660](R 660.0)] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0
>   ))) Unresolved requirements: [[com.adobe.cq.export.json [660](R
>   660.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0
>   )))]

Comment: is `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations-2.8.4` installed and active in system console?

Comment: @awd Yes it is installed and running. There's another bundle (org.apache.sling.models.jacksonexporter) with a dependency on jackson-annotation. This bundle can resolve the dependency just fine though (no error). The only difference I can see is the "Import Packages" statement.

com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation,version=2.8.4 from com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations

As you can see with the jacksonexporter bundle the version number is an explicit one (2.8.4), not a range ([2.8,3))

That's the only difference I am picking up between the working and non-working budles

Thoughts?

Comment: strange..! if you have support from adobe, raise a ticket with them.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add the maven dependencies related to  `com.adobe.cq.export.json` in your POM file.

[image]

I have checked this on AEM 6.3.0

http://localhost:4502/system/console/depfinder

Reference: http://labs.6dglobal.com/blog/2012-05-04/new-cq-55-dependency-finder/